# Saving output of a function which is calling in a for loop in txt (c++)

Tags: c++, save

I call below function in a for loop. In each iteration, it prints some numbers in the terminal. numbers are separated by distance. I want to write numbers in a txt file, so that after program run completely, I can access all numbers in the txt file. This is my function:

```
void printComponents(Components const& cc) 
    {
    auto id = 0;
    for (auto& c : cc) {
        int counter=0;
        for (auto v : c) 
            {
             counter ++;
             }   
        if (counter >1)
            {
            std::cout << " " << counter;     
            }
                         }
     }
```

How can I save numbers in order in txt file?

Comment: Could you provide a complete answer which I can vote to? @Ron

Comment: Just add another parameter `std::ostream& out` and replace `std::cout` with `out`.

Comment: @user0042 Do you mean void printComponents(Components const& cc ,std::ostream& out) 
 {

Comment: Btw. you can achieve this even simpler. In *ix (as well as even on Windows) you may re-direct the standard output of a program. (e.g. `myProgram >output.txt` will save all standard output of `myProgram` in `output.txt`) This is _a_ solution though not a C++ solution (as tagged).

Comment: If so, how should I call the function? @user0042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add another parameter `std::ostream& out` to your function

```
void printComponents(Components const& cc, std::ostream& out)  {
     // ...
}
```

and replace `std::cout` with `out`

```
out << " " << counter;
```

Then open a text file and pass it to your function

```
std::ofstream file("MyFile.txt");
for(...) {
    printComponents(components,file);
}
```

Comment: What is file in last line?

Comment: @Monaphys The `std::ofstream` variable that was constructed in the line before.

Comment: variable ‘std::ofstream file’ has initializer but incomplete type:                                                    std::ofstream file("MyFile.txt");

Comment: @Monaphys Please refer to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) for details about the necessary `#include` statements and such.

Comment: Does it keep numbers created in previous iterations of the for loop?

Comment: @Monaphys I don't know what you mean? The function will output the same to the file as it would otherwise print on the terminal. You can append to the file using the additional [`mode`constructor parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream).

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I am calling the function inside a for loop and I need all values when for loop finished

Comment: @Monaphys Open the file outside of the for loop then.